# How do I get access to the official TESO Forums?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

When I try to register at the official forums, I am [asked for an invitation code](http://forums.elderscrollsonline.com/entry/register?Target=/).

I have looked through all my emails since I bought the game and I am unable to find this code. Can someone explain where I can find it or how I get it?

[image: screenshot of register form]

Comment: I suggest you contact ESO constumer support for the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally one should receive an EMail with such a code after purchasing or registering the game through your Zenimax TESO Account. However, I did not receive such a mail so the only way was to go through Support, which created an account for me.

So the only valid option is to [contact support](http://help.elderscrollsonline.com/).